# Problem rendering leaflet in on dynamic selection from checkbox

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shiny-server

```
type_source <- c("All", "Coal", "Oil", "Gas","Nuclear", "Hydro" ,"Biomass","Wind","Solar", "Geothermal", "Others", "Renewables", "Nonrenewables")
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Project "),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = FALSE, disable = FALSE,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("2018 Data Analysis", tabName = "2018_Data", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("Three Year comparison", tabName = "3_year", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("Entire US", tabName = "US_All", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("Mine", tabName = "Mine", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("About", tabName = "About", icon = NULL)
                   )
                   ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "2018_Data",
              column(width=10, offset=1, 
                     "2018 Data of Illinois",
                     checkboxGroupInput("Type_Source", 
                                        "Type of Source:", type_source,selected = "Renewables",
                                        inline = TRUE)),
              fluidRow(box(leafletOutput(outputId = "illimap")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "3_year"
              # somecode
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "US_All"
               #somecode
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Mine"
               #somecode
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "About"
               #somecode
      )
    )
  )
 
)
```

the above is the UI function of my shiny app. Here I have given check box for different type of sources of energy.

[image: ![enter image description here]

data looks like the above example. PLGENAOL means generation by coal, PLGENAOl and PLGENAGS are generations by oil and gas likewise.
now I want to according to user selection from checkbox, render the leaflet map showing different source generators plant. If a plant has two source then there should two marks of different color at same location. If a person selects any particular type of source then it should show all the plant which have that source.
If a plant has two sources values greater than 0 then that plant has those two source of energy. Like: Anchorage 1 has Oil and gas as its sources. Hence if want to show Anchorage then it should show two different color marks, one for oil and one for gas.
Another case is when a person from checkbox select any particular source then leaflet should show all plants which has those sources. If person selects "All" in the checkbox then all plants should show but the color for different sources should be different. "Renewables" will be a category that includes sources like Hydro, Solar, Wind. So if a person selects Renewables it should give these three sources on map

```
structure(list(PSTATABB = c("Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois", 
"Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois"), PNAME = c("1515 S Caron Road", 
"Adkins Energy LLC", "Agriwind", "Alsey Station", "Altamont", 
"Archer Daniels Midland Co."), LAT = c(41.9084, 42.362222, 41.3017, 
39.569771, 39.068747, 39.870074), LON = c(-89.0466, -89.803611, 
-89.6236, -90.43602, -88.755547, -88.890756), PLNGENAN = c(272, 
27612, 20756, 21066.002, 72, 1332437), PLGENACL = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1326778.88), PLGENAOL = c(0, 0, 0, 18.924, 72, 0), PLGENAGS = c(272, 
27612, 0, 21047.076, 0, 1250.339), PLGENANC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), PLGENAHY = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLGENABM = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), PLGENAWI = c(0, 0, 20756, 0, 0, 0), PLGENASO = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), PLGENAGT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLGENATN = c(272, 
27612, 0, 21066, 72, 1332437), PLGENATR = c(0, 0, 20756, 0, 0, 
0), PLCLPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.995753555327569), PLOLPR = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.000898319567074907, 1, 0), PLGSPR = c(1, 1, 0, 0.999101680432925, 
0, 0.000938385079369606), PLNCPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLHYPR = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLBMPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLWIPR = c(0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0), PLSOPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLGTPR = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), PLTNPR = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), PLTRPR = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0), PLGENAOO = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4407.781), PLOOPR = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.00330805959306144)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]
then I filtered the data for Illinois only named it as Illidata2018
and then

```
d1<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENACL>0,] #Coal
d2<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAOL>0,] #Oil
d3<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAGS>0,] #gas
d4<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENANC>0,] #nuclear
d5<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAHY>0,] #hydro
d6<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENABM>0,] #Biomass
d7<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAWI>0,] #Wind
d8<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENASO>0,] #Solar
d9<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAGT>0,] #geothermal
d10<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAOO>0,] #others

   #filtered for all which have column value greater then zero d1 will be data where all coal plants are there
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    observeEvent(input$Type_Source,{
  
      output$illimap <- renderLeaflet({
        if("All" %in% input$Type_source){
        leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addCircles(data = d1, color='Black')%>%
          addCircles(data = d2,color='red')%>%
        addCircles(data = d3,color='green')%>%
        addCircles(data = d4,color='orange')%>%
        addCircles(data = d5,color='yellow')%>%
        addCircles(data = d6,color='blue')%>%
        addCircles(data = d7,color='pink')%>%
        addCircles(data = d8,color='brown')%>%
        addCircles(data = d9,color='#0CA6AC')%>%
        addCircles(data = d10,color='purple')
        }
        else if("Renewables" %in% input$Type_Source){
          leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addCircles(data = d5,color='yellow')%>%
            addCircles(data = d8,color='brown')%>%
            addCircles(data = d9,color='#0CA6AC')
        }
        else if("Coal" %in% input$Type_source){
          leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addCircles(data = d1,color='black')
            
        }
        })
    })
    
    
     
      
  
    
    
  }
```

I have written this server function. But it is not rendering the leaflet properly. It only shows map when I select "All" from checkbox list. Other than that it is showing a blank area.
Can someone help me in this?

Comment: If you want someone to help you, please post a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some sample data.  Images of data or code is not helpful.

Comment: I made some edits to provide the code and sample data

Comment: Image of data cannot be used by others.  Please use `dput(head(Illidata2018))` and post the output displayed in console into your question.

Comment: Can you pls check now

Answer (score 1):

You just had a typo in `Type_Source`.  Also, as you are using `checkboxGroupInput`, you need to be careful about how you define `All`.  If you mean it to be all the groups, then you need to define it accordingly.  In addition, as multiple groups (for eg: coal and  gas) can be selected, you just need a if statement to enable multiple selections.  Try this

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

df <- structure(list(PSTATABB = c("Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois",
                                  "Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois"),
                     PNAME = c("1515 S Caron Road",
                               "Adkins Energy LLC", "Agriwind", "Alsey Station", "Altamont",
                               "Archer Daniels Midland Co."),
                     LAT = c(41.9084, 42.362222, 41.3017,
                             39.569771, 39.068747, 39.870074),
                     LON = c(-89.0466, -89.803611,
                             -89.6236, -90.43602, -88.755547, -88.890756),
                     PLNGENAN = c(272,
                                  27612, 20756, 21066.002, 72, 1332437),
                     PLGENACL = c(0, 0, 0,
                                  0, 0, 1326778.88),
                     PLGENAOL = c(0, 0, 0, 18.924, 72, 0),
                     PLGENAGS = c(272, 27612, 0, 21047.076, 0, 1250.339),
                     PLGENANC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                  0),
                     PLGENAHY = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLGENABM = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLGENAWI = c(0, 0, 20756, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLGENASO = c(0, 0,
                                  0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLGENAGT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLGENATN = c(272,
                                  27612, 0, 21066, 72, 1332437),
                     PLGENATR = c(0, 0, 20756, 0, 0,          0),
                     PLCLPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.995753555327569),
                     PLOLPR = c(0,     0, 0, 0.000898319567074907, 1, 0),
                     PLGSPR = c(1, 1, 0, 0.999101680432925,
                                0, 0.000938385079369606),
                     PLNCPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLHYPR = c(0,
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLBMPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLWIPR = c(0, 0,
                                1, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLSOPR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     PLGTPR = c(0, 0, 0,
                                0, 0, 0),
                     PLTNPR = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                     PLTRPR = c(0, 0, 1, 0,
                                0, 0),
                     PLGENAOO = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4407.781),
                     PLOOPR = c(0, 0,
                                0, 0, 0, 0.00330805959306144)),
                row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

####

Illidata2018 <- df
type_source <- c("All", "Coal", "Oil", "Gas","Nuclear", "Hydro" ,"Biomass","Wind",
                 "Solar", "Geothermal", "Others", "Renewables", "Nonrenewables")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Project "),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = FALSE, disable = FALSE,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("2018 Data Analysis", tabName = "2018_Data", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("Three Year comparison", tabName = "3_year", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("Entire US", tabName = "US_All", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("Mine", tabName = "Mine", icon = NULL),
                     menuItem("About", tabName = "About", icon = NULL)
                   )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "2018_Data",
              column(width=10, offset=1,
                     "2018 Data of Illinois",
                     checkboxGroupInput("Type_Source",
                                        "Type of Source:",
                                        choices = type_source,
                                        selected = "Renewables",
                                        inline = TRUE)),
              fluidRow(box(leafletOutput(outputId = "illimap")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "3_year"
              # somecode
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "US_All"
              #somecode
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Mine"
              #somecode
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "About"
              #somecode
      )
    )
  )

)

d1<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENACL>0,] #Coal
d2<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAOL>0,] #Oil
d3<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAGS>0,] #gas
d4<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENANC>0,] #nuclear
d5<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAHY>0,] #hydro
d6<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENABM>0,] #Biomass
d7<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAWI>0,] #Wind
d8<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENASO>0,] #Solar
d9<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAGT>0,] #geothermal
d10<-Illidata2018[Illidata2018$PLGENAOO>0,] #others

#filtered for all which have column value greater then zero d1 will be data where all coal plants are there
server <- function(input, output) {

  #observeEvent(input$Type_Source,{

    output$illimap <- renderLeaflet({
      if("All" %in% input$Type_Source){
        leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addCircles(data = d1, color='black')%>%
          addCircles(data = d2,color='red')%>%
          addCircles(data = d3,color='green')%>%
          addCircles(data = d4,color='orange')%>%
          addCircles(data = d5,color='yellow')%>%
          addCircles(data = d6,color='blue')%>%
          addCircles(data = d7,color='pink')%>%
          addCircles(data = d8,color='brown')%>%
          addCircles(data = d9,color='#0CA6AC')%>%
          addCircles(data = d10,color='purple')
      }else{
        p1 <- leaflet() %>%
          addTiles()
          
        if("Coal" %in% input$Type_Source) {
          p1 <- p1 %>% addCircles(data = d1, color='black')
        }
        if("Oil" %in% input$Type_Source) {
          p1 <- p1 %>% addCircles(data = d2, color='red')
        } 
        if(c("Gas","Nonrenewables") %in% input$Type_Source) {
          p1 <- p1 %>% addCircles(data = d3, color='green')
        } 
        if (c("Hydro","Renewables") %in% input$Type_Source) {
          p1 <- p1 %>% addCircles(data = d5,color='yellow')
        } 
        if (c("Solar","Renewables") %in% input$Type_Source) {
          p1 <- p1 %>% addCircles(data = d8,color='brown')
        } 
        if (c("Geothermal","Renewables") %in% input$Type_Source) {
          p1 <- p1 %>% addCircles(data = d9,color='#0CA6AC')
        } 
        
        p1

      }

    })
  #})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I want to give the functionality of selecting multiple option (for eg. Coal and gas) together and then I should be able to render them all. I right now setup some if else statement and I am rendering the the leaflet from inside the if statement and hence if the code enters Coal's if statement, it will render the leaflet and then further gas's f statement will not make any change. How should I render both simultaneouly.

Comment: @PiyushAgrawal, please try the updated code.  You need to complete `if` condition for all other sources.